Issue with vee-validate causing input fields to be misaligned
I'm facing an issue where input fields in a form group are not aligned on the same line when I use vee-validate in my Vue.js project. Without vee-validate, the input fields are perfectly aligned on the same line. Upon inspecting the elements, I noticed that a  element generated by vee-validate is wrapping the input, which seems to be causing the misalignment.
Here's a snippet of my code for context:
           <b-form-group
              label-cols-sm = "6"
                content-cols-sm = '6'
                label="ระยะเวลาของข้อตกลง / Effective Term"
                label-for="input-effective-term"
              >
                <b-input-group>
                  <validation-provider
                    :rules="{ required: true }"
                    name="effective_term_start"
                    v-slot="{ errors }"
                  >
                    <b-form-input
                      v-model="TradeTerm.effective_term_start"
                      type="text"
                      required
                      placeholder="ระยะเวลาเริ่ม"
                      :state="!errors.length"
                      aria-describedby="input-effectiveTerm-Start-feedback"
                    ></b-form-input>
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback v-if="errors.length">
                      {{ errors[0] }}
                    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
                  </validation-provider>
                  <validation-provider
                    :rules="{ required: true }"
                    name="effective_term_end"
                    v-slot="{ errors }"
                  >
                    <b-form-input
                      v-model="TradeTerm.effective_term_end"
                      type="text"
                      required
                      placeholder="ระยะเวลาสิ้นสุด"
                      :state="!errors.length"
                      aria-describedby="input-effectiveTerm-End-feedback"
                    ></b-form-input>
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback v-if="errors.length">
                      {{ errors[0] }}
                    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
                  </validation-provider>
                </b-input-group>
              </b-form-group>

How can I modify my setup to prevent the  from affecting the alignment of the input fields, or is there a better approach to using vee-validate that doesn't cause this issue?
Thank you for your help!
I tried using vee-validate to add validation to my form fields within a Vue.js application. I expected that the form fields would remain aligned on the same line, similar to when vee-validate is not integrated. However, after integrating vee-validate, each input field is wrapped by a  tag generated by vee-validate, which disrupts the alignment, causing the fields to be on separate lines.
This issue seems to be due to the additional  element, which changes the display properties and layout of the form elements. I attempted to override the CSS by setting the  to display: block;, but it did not resolve the alignment issue. I am looking for a way to keep the form inputs aligned on the same line as they were before adding vee-validate.
